# ERB: NameError.message creation does not call #to_s on ruby > 2.0.0

Tags: ruby

I am experiencing strange behaviour when using ERB and implementing #to_s - example:

```
require "erb"
TEMPLATE = "<%= not_here %>"

class A
  def to_s
    "class <A>"
  end
  def to_str
    to_s
  end
  def render
    begin
      ERB.new(TEMPLATE, nil, '-').result(binding)
    rescue Exception => e
      print e.to_s
    end
  end
end


A.new().render
```

On ruby 1.9.3 this prints `undefined local variable or method 'not_here' for class <A>:A`
On ruby 2.0.0 this prints `undefined local variable or method 'not_here' for #<A:0x007f98a29a88b8>`

Can somebody explain why that is the case and what to do about it in order to get the same output on both ruby versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The printed string `#<A:0x007f98a29a88b8>` comes from a call to `inspect` and not from `to_s`.

To get a different output for that part, implement the `inspect` method.

```
class A
  def inspect
    'class <A>'
  end
end
```